# How to use audioop to average sound data

Tags: python, audio, pyaudio

I'm trying to process sound data in a WAV file, involving `audioop.avg()`, but it fails:

```
>>> import audioop, wave
>>> wf = wave.open('sound.wav', 'rb')
>>> averages = [audioop.avg(frame, 4) for frame in wf.readframes(1024)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
audioop.error: not a whole number of frames
```

What does this error mean? The first value it's failing on is '\x00', which is a legitimate whole frame, so I don't understand why it's throwing this exception.

Answer (score 0):

There are (at least) 2 problems:

- You are iterating over the data, therefore sending single bytes to `audioop.avg()`. That's why it's complaining. Just get rid of the `for` and send the data directly into `audioop.avg()`.
- The second argument to `audioop.avg()` should be the sample width, which may or may not be 4. You should use wf.getsampwidth() to find out.

Comment: My end goal is to detect the beginning of speech, so I can't send the whole thing. This is supposed to be part of a "sliding window".

Comment: Well you'll have to call `wf.readframes(1024)` repeatedly, not just once, I guess. You should specify what you'd actually like to achieve. Probably you should do that in a new question ...